# Objective c How to pause and play a game using a button

Tags: objective-c

I want to pause and play my game using the same button. My logic is to use the timer to do this. In my implementation file I have:

```
 -(IBAction)pausePressed{
     if (self.pause){
        [self.timer invalidate];
     else if (!self.pause){
        [self.timer fire];
     }
  }
```

Right now this code allows me to pause the timer hence pausing the game, but when I click on the button to restart the timer nothing happens. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You cannot restart a `NSTimer`. You must create a new one.

Comment: how do i that ? @macmoonshine

Comment: Recreate the object you have originally assigned to `self.timer`.